# An easy way to calculate the residue of $\tan^2z$

Tags: complex-analysis, taylor-expansion, residue-calculus, laurent-series

I need to calculate the value of residue of $f(z) = \tan^2z$ at $z_k=\frac{\pi}{2} + \pi k$. I know that these points are poles of the second order, so the common way is to calculate residue by the formula.
$$
Res_{z_k}(\tan^2z) = \lim_{z\to z_k}\frac{d}{dz}((z-z_k)^2\cdot\tan^2(z))
$$
But this limit is very unpleasant to calculate, at least for me. Maybe I am missing something?

The other way is to calculate the Laurent series at $z_k$. And the only way I see to do so, is by dividing the squares of the Taylor series of sine and cosine, which is also a hell of a thing to do.

Comment: Generally using Taylor and Laurent series themselves is much better for computing residues. Calculating those limits can be a pain

Comment: Your last paragraph is simply false. If you write $\zeta=z-\frac{\pi}{2}$, then you've got to expand $\frac{\cos\zeta}{\sin\zeta}$ which is easily seen to be $\frac{1}{\zeta^2}(1-\frac12 \zeta^2+O(\zeta^3))^2(1-\frac16\zeta^2+O(\zeta^3))^{-2}$ which is easily $\frac{1}{\zeta^2}+O(1)$ so the residue is $0$. [@Martin R gives a better solution to this precise case, but I wanted to point out to you how easy it is to use Taylor series.]

Comment: Well actually I got that, but wasn't sure if it is correct, so thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The residue of $\tan(z)^2$ at $\frac{\pi}{2} + \pi k$ is equal to the residue of
$$
 z \mapsto \tan(z - \frac{\pi}{2} - \pi k)^2
$$
at $z=0$. But that is an *even* function, so that its Laurent series at $z=0$ has only terms with even exponents. In particular, the residue at $z=0$ is zero.

Comment: Thank you! That was really smart! The problem is that I was asked to find this on my exam yesterday and the teacher asked me to calculate this by using the formula and by writing down several terms of Laurent series. (I suspect that they just wanted to fail me, because of some reasons, but it doesn't really matter at this point)